# PHP Multiple Textbox Array POST

Tags: php

```
<form method="post">
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++)
{
    for($j = 1; $j <= 100; $j++)
    {
        echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"text" . $j . "[]\" value=\"" . ($i * $j) . "\" />";
    }
}
?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Why only get 10 rows output when post 1000 rows?
Already seated all variable in php.ini like input_max_var, max_execution_time, max_post_limit etc...

**OUTPUT**

```html
Array
(
    [text1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 6
            [6] => 7
            [7] => 8
            [8] => 9
            [9] => 10
        )
    [text2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 8
            [4] => 10
            [5] => 12
            [6] => 14
            [7] => 16
            [8] => 18
            [9] => 20
        )
    .
    .
    .
    [text100] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 200
            [2] => 300
            [3] => 400
            [4] => 500
            [5] => 600
            [6] => 700
            [7] => 800
            [8] => 900
            [9] => 1000
        )
)
```

```
memory_limit = -1
post_max_size = 1G
max_execution_time = -1
max_input_time = -1
max_input_vars = -1
suhosin.post.max_vars = -1
suhosin.request.max_vars = -1
```

Comment: unclear of what you are saying. also provide a sample input/output and what you've tried.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you please elaborate your problem by adding some real code like HTML and PHP code?

Comment: What limit set in php.ini?

Comment: You are over-writing your named array again and again

Comment: memory_limit = -1
post_max_size = 1G
max_execution_time = -1
max_input_time = -1
max_input_vars = -1
suhosin.post.max_vars = -1
suhosin.request.max_vars = -1